# HTML5 validation error: Element source not allowed as a child element of audio in this context

Tags: html, html5-audio, w3c-validation

This is a snippet of code from my assignment. I've checked the w3 samples http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp and it is formatted correctly. Am I just going crazy because of these errors or did I miss something?

I believe it's that the HTML5 `source` element doesn't like how the type is written in but how else would I do it? Please let me know if you guys see anything I'm just missing.

```
<li>.ogg(HTML5 <code>audio</code> tag)
            <ul>
                <li style="list-style-type:none;">

                    <audio controls>
    `                   <source src="/audio1/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
                        <!-- IE Support -->
                        <source src="http://itwp.macomb.edu/wannerj/itwp1000/sounds/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                        Your browser does not support the audio element.
                    </audio>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: Please avoid using w3schools.com. It is not associated in any way with the W3C, and it is sloppy and unreliable and very poorly maintained. Please instead use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/); for example, the MDN [Using HTML5 audio and video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) page.

Answer (score 4):

Maintainer of the W3C HTML Checker here. The problem is that you have a stray `` ` `` (backtick) character in your HTML, on the line after the `<audio controls>` start tag and before the `<source src="/audio1/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">` start tag.

Remove that `` ` `` character and the error will disappear.

---

#### Explanation

The reason the validator is showing that error message in this case is that when it sees that `` ` `` character, it interprets it as text content (fallback content) to show to users in browsers that don’t support the `audio` element; that is, the same as the "`Your browser does not support the audio element`" text in the snippet in the question.

But if an `audio` element has such text content, then the rules in the HTML spec state that no elements are allowed to follow that text content. So when the checker sees the `source` element in this case, it emits an error message saying the `source` element is not allowed.

I’m sorry the checker doesn’t give a better error message here to help you pinpoint the problem; for example, it would be much better if it said something like:

> The `source` element is not allowed here because this `audio` element 
>   already has text content (`` ` ``); remove the text content or move it
>   to follow the `source` element.

But the current design of the code for the checker makes it very difficult to have it produce a more-helpful detailed error message like that.

Comment: An invisible character such as a newline character can cause the same error! Copy/pasting can bring in that newline character and result in this same error message.